# Why did Nifty50 close at 15557 when it was at 15582 at 3:30 pm IST?

Tags: options, equities

I am a student and trader. I was recently interested in f&o trading recently, so I decided to enter with a hedge strategy. I saw the market go in my favour as the clock reached 3:30 and Nifty was at 15582. But when it was 3:31, Nifty50 was at 15557. Can someone please tell me what price will be excercised when the contract is ended?

Answer (score 1):

Settlement price for Nifty Index options is weighted average of last 30min price on expiry day. So it’ll be neither of these.